# Changing views/activity in Android

Tags: java, android, view, android-activity

I am a newbie in Android and currently I am designing an application where I have faced a big problem with changing views. I have 3 classes, each one for a different screen. I use a button to change pages but it does not seem to work. Every time I move to the next screen, the variables methods etc of the 2nd screen are located in a different class. Can you please show me the simplest way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: Follow Sadeshkumar's answer. The button should raise an intent to start a new activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place each screen in different **Activity**. Start respective activities according to button presses. To pass data between activities use **Intent**.

[Activity Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

[Intent Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

[Simple Example for Activities and Intents](http://mobileorchard.com/android-app-development-using-intents-to-pass-data-and-return-results-between-activities/)

Comment: The last link was all i needed. Thank you a lot